# Using a delay function inside another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and I have a ptoblem with a code that looks like this:

```
function job1() {
    var subText1="";
    var subText2="";
    var text="";
    var vocabulary = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    // Use the delay function to create a full text in 20 * 150 milliseconds
    var i = 0, 
    action = function() {
                var temp = vocabulary.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * vocabulary.length));
                text+= temp;
                document.write(text + "<br>");
                i++;
                if (i < 20) {
                            setTimeout(action, 150);
                } else {
                    // The first subText is from position 0 until some random number random between 0 and the text length
                    subText1 = text.slice(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length));
                    // The second subText is from where the first subText ends until the last character form the text input
                    subText2 = text.slice(subText1.length, text.length);

                    // output of the subText1 and the subText2 for the first time
                    document.write("subText1: " + subText1 + "<br>");
                    document.write("subText2: " + subText2 + "<br>");
                    document.write("text: " + text + "<br>");
                }
            };

        setTimeout(action, 0);

        // output of the subText1 and the subText2 once more
        document.write("subText1: " + subText1 + "<br>");
        document.write("subText2: " + subText2 + "<br>");

        // NextJob: job2, job3
        // job dependency
        var nextJob = "job2, job3";
        var prevJob = "null";

        // results
        return { 
        subText1_RT : subText1,
        subText2_RT : subText2
        };
}
```

my problem is that I need to  to get the `subText1` and the `subText2` from the `action = function()....` section into this section:

```
return { 
   subText1_RT : subText1,
   subText2_RT : subText2
};
```

But the `subText1` and the `subText2` variables are empty.

Here is a fiddle to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/TalGoz/4tgc372e/

It looks like all the parts of the `job1()` function are executed before the `action = function()` part. It is very important to get it working like this as function inside a function, I can’t separate the functions for the purpose of my goal.

I hope someone here can help me see the problem and solve it.

Comment: setTimeout and return, do not make sense together.

Comment: @epascarello Why? I don't see any problems using it here. There is nothing wrong with `document.write` if used correctly. The problem is misuse, not don't use.

Comment: OP is running setTimeout and document.write, it will replace the page content. Bad use here and 99% of the time it is the wrong thing to use.

Comment: @epascarello the document.write is only to see the output.

Comment: @epascarello I just want to use the `setTimeout` to create my text slowly ,after that I want to do something with the text and then return the results using the 2 variables inside the `job1()`.

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method. You would need to use a callback to do the final steps after it has completed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: @epascarello could you please give me a small example of a callback regarding my code?

Comment: @TalG, look for a solution to your problem in this question, which is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455134/javascript-doesnt-seem-to-wait-for-return-values    The issue here is that the (job1) function returns before the (action) function even executes, so the subtext values aren't set yet.

Comment: @EdBayiates thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: The final processing of your text values needs to be in a callback function because of the way JavaScript works -- it is single threaded, meaning only one piece of code runs at a time.  Looking at your original code, execution first goes into `job1()`.  It builds `action()` as a function *without executing it* and them moves on to the setTimeout(), which sets up `action()` to run but doesn't run it yet.  For a setTimeout() to actually execute, even with time value 0, the current code has to finish executing.  Next it moves on to the end code in `job1()` which is document.Write, job1/job3, and returning the object.  Since `action()` has not yet executed, the subText objects are not yet set.

Once control has left `job1()`, and finished any current code, the browser will start executing `action()` from your setTimeout() call.  Inside `action()` there are other setTimeout calls, and those behave similarly -- the current code must finish executing, then there's a wait, and then finally the code specified will execute.

So in summary, you must use a callback function because *execution must finish with all current code* before any code queued up with setTimeout() will execute.  You can't take an asynchronous function like `job1()` and make it synchronous because none of the async setTimeout() calls can possibly execute while you're inside `job1()`.

In certain other languages, like C++ or Java, you can make code run in parallel, so you can spawn code in a "background thread" and then the current thread can wait for it to finish, giving you the effect you want.  You cannot do this with JavaScript.  All async functions require a callback.  Callback literally means, "Call me back when you're done".  In the future, there will be Web Workers which may support multiple pieces of code running at a time: [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Here is an example using a callback `whendone`, which is referenced below.  It gets called when the values have been set.

```
function job1(whendone) {
    var subText1="";
    var subText2="";
    var text="";
    var vocabulary = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    // Use the delay function to create a full text in 20 * 150 milliseconds
    var i = 0, 
    action = function() {
            var temp = vocabulary.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * vocabulary.length));
            text+= temp;
            document.write(text + "<br>");
            i++;
            if (i < 20) {
                        setTimeout(action, 150);
            } else {
                // The first subText is from position 0 until some random number random between 0 and the text length
                subText1 = text.slice(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length));
                // The second subText is from where the first subText ends until the last character form the text input
                subText2 = text.slice(subText1.length, text.length);

                // output of the subText1 and the subText2 for the first time
                document.write("subText1: " + subText1 + "<br>");
                document.write("subText2: " + subText2 + "<br>");
                document.write("text: " + text + "<br>");

                // Now we're done
                whendone(subText1, subText2);
            }
        };

    setTimeout(action, 0);
}

job1(function(subText1, subText2) {
    // output of the subText1 and the subText2 once more
    document.write("subText1: " + subText1 + "<br>");
    document.write("subText2: " + subText2 + "<br>");

    // NextJob: job2, job3
    // job dependency
    var nextJob = "job2, job3";
    var prevJob = "null";

    // results
    var returned = { 
        subText1_RT : subText1,
        subText2_RT : subText2
    };

    // Your code doing something with 'returned' here
});
```

The value you want ends up in `returned`.  If you want to do something with the value, add code after the `returned =` statement.

Comment: Thanks for this code!!!, is it possible to capsule the whole thing in one function let’s say `function job(){...}` which will have the output parameters at the end. The thing is with this solution is that at the end I have 2 separate functions that interact with each other. I actually need one `function job(){...}` that I can call and this function can have others functions inside like you have in your example, but at the end only by calling the `job()` function (which capsules all the other) I want to get the results. Again thanks for the code!

Comment: @TalG, there isn't any way to have a single function.  I'll edit my answer to explain more about why.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)